# Video streaming on windows phone gives "3100 An error has occurred"

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, h.264

Initial data:

- windows phone 7.1 application;
- video streaming (video: MPEG‐4 AVC (part 10) (H.264); audio: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a));
- not a smooth streaming;
- opened in VLC with any problems;
- all capabilities are included (ID_CAP_MEDIALIB, ID_CAP_MICROPHONE, ID_CAP_NETWORKING and other).

I am using a MediaElement for opening video stream with custom http url:

```
media.Source = new Uri("streaming url");
media.DownloadProgressChanged += this.media_DownloadProgressChanged;
media.MediaFailed += this.media_MediaFailed;
media.MediaEnded += this.media_MediaEnded;
media.Play();
```

MediaFailed gives "3100 An error has occurred" error without any additional description.

Seems like [listed codecs are supported](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-7-audio-media-codecs).

Also I tried this code:

```
var mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher
{
   Location = MediaLocationType.Install,
   Media = new Uri("streaming url", UriKind.Absolute),
   Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All,
};
mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```

but media player was not able to play video.

What can cause a problem? How to test whether video stream is compatible with Windows Phone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Check video format. Upload it via zune to the device, and play it on the device.
2. Check if this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201886/h-264-video-play-using-mediastreamsource-meet-with-3100-mediaerror-on-wp7-emul

Comment: 3. Check if ID_CAP_MEDIALIB is really included. AppHub detects which  caps are used and updates the manifest
4. Maybe you should set metadata before playing:

videoStreamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.CodecPrivateData] = "";
videoStreamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.VideoFourCC] = "H264";
videoStreamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.Width] = "WIDTH HERE";
videoStreamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.Height] = "HEIGHT HERE";
Details here (use translator)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/windowsphonezhchs/thread/1fa21a6f-267a-4930-9826-7247e4bcbc54

Comment: hi there, did you solve this issue